# Linux miniPC for collecting data from sensors

Tags: linux, mini-pc

I'm looking for mini (micro) PC with low parameters just enough to run Linux. I found some devices, but too strong and mostly without GSM.

Required parameters:

- Processor architecture to run Linux
- Memory at least 2GB
- USB 2/3 port
- Ethernet 100
- GSM SIM card (alternate data channel)
- SSD memory card at least 5GB

It should be middle agent for trasmitting data from sensors (company lan/usb) to cloud on internet.

I know raspberrypi device, which is perfect with parameters, but i am not sure, it is good enough for industry enviroment (24h/day).

Thank You for any recommends

--- UPDATE

Finally i found first product with all interfaces
https://www.axotec.de/en/products/4g-lte-iot-gateway/industrial-computer-rgx-840-flex.html

Comment: What kind of sensor are we talking here? What software is running to pull data from these sensors?

Comment: Sensors are connected via LAN (SNMP) or USB (radio) . Software is just script in python to read usb and send snmp commands.

Comment: What are your requirements? Industrial might mean a lot of things. Extreme temperatures, vibrations, other things.

Comment: @webbee you'd be surprised how common RS485 is. Or even RS232. Or there are current loops too.

Comment: industrial.. i mean not for home use, tested for 24h/day running, maybe ip68. Many minipc products are for desktop, i am looking for small server with described interfaces. Better keyword is "iot gateway" .. finally i found one https://www.axotec.de/en/products/4g-lte-iot-gateway/industrial-computer-rgx-840-flex.html

Answer (score 1):

A Raspberry Pi or Intel NUC would be your best bets. You would have to purchase a HAT or USB GSM module for the Pi. The NUC will accept the USB version.

Comment: I know these boards, but i need tested and ready to go solution - in box from supplier with warranty and good support.